# Matlab: How to link each note to a key if all keys are called to one function

Tags: matlab

In an exercise, we create piano keys which, when pressed, plays the required note.

Normally we call each key to its distinct function, as shown below.

```
function keysound
f=figure('Visible','off')
c_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','C','Position',[140,80 40 160],'Callback',@c_keybutton) 
%Pushbutton, @ 140,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'C', calls the keySound function
d_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','D','Position',[180 80 40 160],'Callback',@d_keybutton) 
%Pushbutton, @ 180,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'D', calls the keySound function
e_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','E','Position',[220 80 40 160],'Callback',@e_keybutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 220,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'E', calls the keySound function
f_key =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','F','Position',[260 80 40 160],'Callback',@f_keybutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 260,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'F', calls the keySound function
g_key =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','G','Position',[300 80 40 160],'Callback',@g_keybutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 380,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'B', calls the keySound function
c_sharp =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','C#','Position',...
    [160 180 40 100],'Background','black','ForeGround','white','Callback',@c_sharpbutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 160,80, Size 40x100, labeled 'C#', background is black, foregrou, calls the keySound function
e_flat =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Eb','Position',...
    [200 180 40 100],'Background','black','ForeGround','white','Callback',@e_flatbutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 300,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'G', calls the keySound function
a_key =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','A','Position',[340 80 40 160],'Callback',@a_keybutton) 
%Pushbutton, @ 340,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'A', calls the keySound function
b_key =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','B','Position',[380 80 40 160],'Callback',@b_keybutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 200,80, Size 40x100, labeled 'Eb', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
f_sharp =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','F#','Position',[280 180 40 100],...
    'Background','black','ForeGround','white','Callback',@f_sharpbutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 280,80, Size 40x100, labeled 'F#', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
g_sharp =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','G#','Position',...
    [320 180 40 100],'Background','black','ForeGround','white','Callback',@g_sharpbutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 320,80, Size 40x100, labeled 'G#', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
b_flat =  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Bb','Position',...
    [360 180 40 100],'Background','black','ForeGround','white','Callback',@b_flatbutton)
%Pushbutton, @ 360,80, Size 40x100, labeled 'Bb', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function

f.Visible='on'

freq = [261.626, 277.183, 293.665, 311.127, 329.628, 349.228, 369.994, ...
    391.995, 415.305, 440.000, 466.164, 493.883]; %Provided frequencies of each note
sample = 8192;%Default sampling rate of the sound() command
% HINT: Begin by getting the 'String' property from the pressed button, you'll need it to determine which frequency
% you'll use.
% Begin your code after this line
dur = 0.6 %Set this to .6, which will be your duration
vals = 0:(1/sample):dur %This will be an array of values, from 0 to dur, in steps of the inverse of the sample rate


     function c_keybutton(c_key,event)
     R1=10*sin(2*pi*freq(1)*vals)
     sound(R1)
    end

     function d_keybutton(d_key,event)
     R2=10*sin(2*pi*freq(3)*vals)
     sound(R2)
     end

     function e_keybutton(e_key,event)
     R3=10*sin(2*pi*freq(5)*vals)
     sound(R3)
     end

      function f_keybutton(f_key,event)
      R4=10*sin(2*pi*freq(6)*vals)
      sound(R4)
      end
      function g_keybutton(g_key,event)      
      R5=10*sin(2*pi*freq(8)*vals)
      sound(R5)
     end

      function a_keybutton(a_key,event)
      R6=10*sin(2*pi*freq(10)*vals)
      sound(R6)
      end 
     function b_keybutton(b_key,event)
         R7=10*sin(2*pi*freq(12)*vals)
         sound(R7)
     end

     function c_sharpbutton(c_sharp,event)
         R8=10*sin(2*pi*freq(2)*vals)
        sound(R8)
     end

     function e_flatbutton(e_flat,event)
         R9=10*sin(2*pi*freq(4)*vals)
        sound(R9)
    end
     function f_sharpbutton(f_sharp,event)
         R10=10*sin(2*pi*freq(7)*vals)         
         sound(R10)
     end
    function g_sharpbutton(g_sharp,event)
        R11=10*sin(2*pi*freq(9)*vals)
        sound(R11)
    end
    function b_flatbutton(b_flat,event)
        R12=10*sin(2*pi*freq(11)*vals)
         sound(R12)
     end


end
```

However, the exercise demands this is split into two parts.

In the first part, we create a script which outlines the keys of the piano. We call only the "keySound" function.

```
c_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','C','Position',[140 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound) 
%Pushbutton, @ 140,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'C', calls the keySound function
d_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','D','Position',[180 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 180,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'D', calls the keySound function
e_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','E','Position',[220 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 220,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'E', calls the keySound function
f_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','F','Position',[260 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 260,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'F', calls the keySound function
g_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','G','Position',[300 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 300,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'G', calls the keySound function
a_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','A','Position',[340 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 340,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'A', calls the keySound function
b_key = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','B','Position',[380 80 40 160],'Callback',@keySound) 
%Pushbutton, @ 380,80, Size 40x160, labeled 'B', calls the keySound function
c_sharp = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','C#','Position',[160 180 40 100],'BackgroundColor','black'...
    ,'Foreground','white','Callback',@keySound) 
%Pushbutton, @ 160,180, Size 40x100, labeled 'C#', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
e_flat = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Eb','Position',[200 180 40 100],'BackgroundColor','black',...
    'ForegroundColor','white','Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 200,180, Size 40x100, labeled 'Eb', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
f_sharp = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','F#','Position',[280 180 40 100],...,
    'BackgroundColor','black','ForegroundColor','white','Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 280,180, Size 40x100, labeled 'F#', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
g_sharp = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','G#','Position',[320 180 40 100],...
    'BackgroundColor','black','ForegroundColor','white','Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 320,180, Size 40x100, labeled 'G#', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
b_flat = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Bb','Position',[360 180 40 100],...
    'BackgroundColor','black','ForegroundColor','white','Callback',@keySound)
%Pushbutton, @ 360,180, Size 40x100, labeled 'Bb', background is black, foreground is white, calls the keySound function
```

In the second part, the following (quoted below) is required.

"The second part of this problem will be devoted to designing the callback function for the piano keys. When a key is pressed, it will call this function, which will play the note associated with that key. This function will play sound (using the sound() command)."

"Once you complete this, try copy/pasting both parts into matlab (as seperate files), and running the GUI script. Your GUI should pop up, and you should hear notes when you press the buttons!"

They give hints in the form of a code.

```
    function wave = keySound(hObject, Data)
%%Problem 10.1.2 is designed by Benjamin Szafarz for MATLAB 2017a
% function keySound(hObject, Data) is called when pressed by ANY of the keys in your piano GUI
% The aim of this function is to play the note of the pressed key, which you will do by first creating the note
% then playing it using the sound() command. Note that the sound() command takes an input of wave data.
% The wave data is a sin wave, created by you, in the form: A * sin(2*pi*<frequency>*<values array>), where
% A is 10, the frequency is the frequency of the note being played, and the values array is the array of values
% which you will create. The frequencies of the notes (in ascending order) are provided, as well as the default
% sampling rate for the sound() command. 
% OUTPUT: wave, an array containing the wave data (your input for sound() ).
freq = [261.626, 277.183, 293.665, 311.127, 329.628, 349.228, 369.994, ...
    391.995, 415.305, 440.000, 466.164, 493.883]; %Provided frequencies of each note
sample = 8192;%Default sampling rate of the sound() command
% HINT: Begin by getting the 'String' property from the pressed button, you'll need it to determine which frequency
% you'll use.
% Begin your code after this line
dur = .6; %Set this to .6, which will be your duration
vals = 0:(1/sample):1; %This will be an array of values, from 0 to dur, in steps of the inverse of the sample rate
end
```

However, I'm unsure how to link each key to its note if all the keys call the same function.

Comment: `Data` contains information on what key was pressed.

Comment: @excaza Right, but how do I assign a note to each key.

Comment: You know the key and you have a list of frequencies. Match the key to the frequency.

Comment: @excaza What would the code look like? What variables should I use?

Comment: Try making some `if` statements. This is homework, put some thought into it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

```
b_flat = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Bb','Position',[360 180 40 100],...
'BackgroundColor','black','ForegroundColor','white','Callback',{@keySound,1})
```

The function call should is similar to this:

```
function keySound(~,~,Id)
%Execution when button is pressed
switch Id

case 1
    %....

otherwise

end

return;
```